# Detecting bad UTF-8 encoding: list of bad characters to sniff?

Tags: encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I have a sql-server 2010 database shared between two applications. One application we have control over, and the other application is a third-party app that created the database in the first place. Our app is a CRM built on top of the third party webmail app.

The database contains varchar columns and is latin-1 encoded. The third-party app is written in php and doesn't care about correctly encoding the data, so it stuffs utf-8 encoded bytes into the varchar columns, where they are interpreted as latin-1 and look like garbage.

Our CRM app is written in .Net, which automagically detects that the database collation is different the the encoding of the string in memory, so when .Net writes to a database, it converts the bytes to match the database encoding.

So... data written to the db from our app looks correct in the db, but data from the third party app doesn't.

when our app writes FirstName = Céline, it is stored in the db as Céline

when the webmail app writes FirstName = Céline it is stored in the db as CÃ©line

Our CRM app needs to display contacts that were created in either system. So I'm writing an EncodingSniffer class that looks for flagged characters that indicate its a poorly encoded string and converts them.

currently I have:

```
private static string[] _flaggedChars = new string[] { 
            "Ã©" 
        };
```

which works great for displaying CÃ©line as Céline, but I need to add to the list.

Does anyone know of a resource to get all the possible ways that utf-8 special chars could be interpreted as iso-8859-1?

Thanks

**Clarification:**

Since i am working in .Net. The string, when loaded into memory from the database, is converted to Unicode UTF-16. So, regardless of if it was encoded correctly in the database. It is now represented as UTF16 bytes. I need to be able to analyze thes UTF-16 bytes, and determine if they are screwed up due to utf-8 bytes being stuffed into an iso-8859-1 database.... clear as mud right?

Here is what i have so far. It has cleaned up the display of most misencoded characters, but I am still having trouble with É
for instance: Éric is stored in the db by webmail as Ã‰ric, but after detecting bad encoding and changing it back, it displays as �?ric
Looking at a user who has 2500 contacts, hundreds of which had encoding issues, the É is the only thing that isn't displaying correctly...

```
public static Regex CreateRegex()
    {
        string specials = "ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö";

        List<string> flags = new List<string>();
        foreach (char c in specials)
        {
            string interpretedAsLatin1 = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(c.ToString())).Trim();//take the specials, treat them as utf-8, interpret them as latin-1
            if (interpretedAsLatin1.Length > 0)//utf-8 chars made up of 2 bytes, interpreted as two single byte latin-1 chars.
                flags.Add(interpretedAsLatin1);
        }

        string regex = string.Empty;
        foreach (string s in flags)
        {
            if (regex.Length > 0)
                regex += '|';
            regex += s;
        }
        return new Regex("(" + regex + ")");
    }

    public static string CheckUTF(string data)
    {
        Match match = CreateRegex().Match(data);
        if (match.Success)
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetBytes(data));//from iso-8859-1 (latin-1) to utf-8
        else
            return data;
    }
```

So: É is being converted to 195'Ã',8240'‰'

Comment: is it an option to change the DB encoding to UTF-8, seems like the simplest solution since there is not a 1 to 1 conversion between unicode and latin-1

Comment: Testing whether the string is valid UTF-8 might be a better approach. (Probably less expensive too.)

Comment: @Mat, that is essentially what i'm trying to do, i just don't know how. and the bad character sniffing approach was the best i came up with. How would you go about testing for valid utf-8?

Comment: @Evan, nope, not an option in sqlserver 2010. We did try switching the datatypes of the columns to nvarchar.. but the app creates sql query strings instead of using sprocs. So we think its probably saying: set column = 'somestring', instead of: set column = N'somestring', so even with the nvarchar columns, it was still stuffing varchar data...

Comment: http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-forms-utf-8 for example. (Not 100% reliable.)

Comment: @Mat, thats perfect, you should put that in an answer instea of a comment so I can mark it answered and you get your rep points.. if you care about that.

Comment: Got lotsa rep already, and wouldn't know how to adapt that to a SQL Server environment at all. If you do manage to implement something like that, please do post the gist of it as an answer though, could be useful for others.

Comment: Do you know that those two variations are not just fully composed and fully decomposed UTF8 representations of the same thing?

Comment: @Paul, can you clarify, I"m new to dealing with encoding issues

Comment: @Michael, it's called equivalence (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence).  Example: the 'o' with an umlaut character 'ö' can be represented as either that specific character (fully composed) or as an 'o' with an umlaut diacrtic (decomposed), such that the two combine into the same character when displayed.

Comment: @Michael The É in Éric is fixed by using encoding "Windows-1252" (Western European) or "windows-1254" (Turkish), instead of "iso-8859-1" in CheckUTF(). No Unicode de/re-normalization needed. (I'm sure it's been bugging you forever) Thanks for the code!

Comment: Thanks @Michael, @Qubei; this gave me a simple PS script to convert such issues: `<# Desired Result: 'Strømmen' #>;$x = 'StrÃ¸mmen'; $bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding('Windows-1252').GetBytes($x); [system.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($bytes,0,$bytes.Length)`

Answer (score 1):

You should probably just try to decode the byte string as UTF-8, and if you get an error, assume it's ISO-8859-1 instead.

Text that is encoded as ISO-8859-1 rarely "happens" to also be valid UTF-8... unless it's ISO-8859-1 that only actually contains ASCII, but then in that case you don't have a problem at all, of course. So this method is reasonably robust.

Ignoring which characters occur more frequently than others in actual language, here is a naive analysis that assumes that each character occurs with the same frequency. Let's try to find out how frequently valid ISO-8859-1 can be mistaken for UTF-8 resulting in mojibake. I also assume that C1 control characters (U+0080 through U+009F) don't occur.

For any given byte in the byte string. If the byte is close to the end of the string then you are even more likely to detect malformed UTF-8 because some byte sequences will be known to be not long enough to be valid UTF-8. But assuming the byte is not near the end of the string:

- p(byte decodes as ASCII) = 0.57. This gives no information about whether the string is ASCII, ISO-8859-1, or UTF-8.
- If this byte is 0x80 through 0xc1 or 0xf8 through 0xff, it can't be UTF-8, so you'll detect that. p=0.33
- If this first byte is 0xc2 through 0xdf (p=0.11) then it could be valid UTF-8, but only if it's followed by a byte with value between 0x80 and 0xbf. The probability that the next byte fails to be in that range is 192/224 = 0.86. So the probability that UTF-8 fails here is 0.09
- If the first byte is 0xe0 through 0xef then it could be valid UTF-8 but only if it's followed by 2 continuation bytes. The probability that you will detect bad UTF-8 is thus (16/224)*(1-(0.14*0.14)) = 0.07
- Similar for 0xf0 through 0xf7, the probability is (8/224)*(1-(0.14*0.14*0.14)) = 0.04.

At each byte in a long string, the probability of detecting bad UTF-8 is 0.33+0.09+0.07+0.04 = 0.53.

So for a long string, the probability that ISO-8859-1 will pass silently through a UTF-8 decoder is very small: it approximately halves for each additional character!

This analysis of course assumes random ISO-8859-1 characters. In practice the misdetection rate will not be quite as good as that (mostly on account of the fact that most bytes in real-world text are actually ASCII), but it will still be very good.

Comment: Can anyone provide a .net code sample of this?
I can't find something that throws an exception. Everything I try just make the encoding look even more messed up.

Comment: Actually, i think i see why this doesn't work. Since all strings in .Net are UTF-16, the original bytes from the database have already been modified by the time I try to decode them in application code. So I'm getting my byte array from a utf-16 string and trying to decode to utf-8...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Michael for doing over 99% of the work!

Here's a PowerShell version of Michael's script for anyone it helps.  This also @Qubei's suggestion of the `Windows-1252` code page/encoding to resolve the `É` issue; though allows you to amend these encodings in case your data became corrupt via a different combination of encodings.

```
#based on c# in question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484833/detecting-bad-utf-8-encoding-list-of-bad-characters-to-sniff
function Convert-CorruptCodePageString {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'ByInputText')]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true, ParameterSetName = 'ByInputText')]
        [string]$InputText
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true, ParameterSetName = 'ByInputObject')]
        [PSObject]$InputObject
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'ByInputObject')]
        [string]$Property
        ,
        [Parameter()]
        [System.Text.Encoding]$SourceEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding('Windows-1252')
        ,
        [Parameter()]
        [System.Text.Encoding]$DestinationEncoding = [system.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
        ,
        [Parameter()]
        [string]$DodgyChars = 'ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö'
    )
    begin {
        [string]$InvalidCharRegex = ($DodgyChars.ToCharArray() | %{
            [byte[]]$dodgyCharBytes = $DestinationEncoding.GetBytes($_.ToString())
            $SourceEncoding.GetString($dodgyCharBytes,0,$dodgyCharBytes.Length).Trim()
        })  -join '|'   
    }
    process {
        if ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'ByInputText') {
            $InputObject = $null
        } else {
            $InputText = $InputObject."$Property"
        }
        [bool]$IsLikelyCorrupted = $InputText -match $InvalidCharRegex
        if ($IsLikelyCorrupted) { #only bother to decrupt if we think it's corrupted
            [byte[]]$bytes = $SourceEncoding.GetBytes($InputText)
            [string]$outputText = $DestinationEncoding.GetString($bytes,0,$bytes.Length)
        } else {
            [string]$outputText = $InputText
        }
        [pscustomobject]@{
            InputString = $InputText
            OutputString = $outputText
            InputObject = $InputObject
            IsLikelyCorrupted = $IsLikelyCorrupted
        }        
    }
}
```

**Demo**

```
#demo of using a simple string without the function (may cause corruption since this doesn't check if the characters being replaced are those likely to have been corrupted / thus is more likely to cause corruption in many strings).
$x = 'StrÃ¸mmen'
$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding('Windows-1252').GetBytes($x)
[system.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($bytes,0,$bytes.Length)

#demo using the function
$x | Convert-CorruptCodePageString

#demo of checking all records in a table for an issue / reporting those with issues
#amend SQL Query, MyDatabaseInstance, and MyDatabaseCatlogue to point to your DB / query the relevant table
Invoke-SQLQuery -Query 'Select [Description], [RecId] from [DimensionFinancialTag] where [Description] is not null and [Description] > ''''' -DbInstance $MyDatabaseInstance -DbCatalog $MyDatabaseCatalog |
    Convert-CorruptCodePageString -Property 'Description' | 
    ?{$_.IsLikelyCorrupted} | 
    ft @{N='RecordId';E={$_.InputObject.RecId}}, InputString, OutputString
```

**Additional Function used in my Demo**

I'm not a fan of the `Invoke-SqlCmd` cmdlet, so rolled my own.

```
function Invoke-SQLQuery {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'ByQuery')]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$DbInstance
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$DbCatalog
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'ByQuery')]
        [string]$Query
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'ByPath')]
        [string]$Path
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [hashtable]$Params = @{}
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [int]$CommandTimeoutSeconds = 30 #this is the SQL default
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [System.Management.Automation.Credential()]
        [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$Credential=[System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]::Empty 
    )
    begin {
        write-verbose "Call to 'Execute-SQLQuery'"
        $connectionString = ("Server={0};Database={1}" -f $DbInstance,$DbCatalog)
        if ($Credential -eq [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]::Empty) {
            $connectionString = ("{0};Integrated Security=True" -f $connectionString)
        } else {
            $connectionString = ("{0};User Id={1};Password={2}" -f $connectionString, $Credential.UserName, $Credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password)    
            $PSCmdlet.Name    
        }
        $connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
        $connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
        $connection.Open()    
    }
    process {
        #create the command & assign the connection
        $cmd = new-object -TypeName 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand'
        $cmd.Connection = $connection

        #load in our query
        switch ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName) {
            'ByQuery' {$cmd.CommandText = $Query; break;}
            'ByPath' {$cmd.CommandText = Get-Content -Path $Path -Raw; break;}
            default {throw "ParameterSet $($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName) not recognised by Invoke-SQLQuery"}
        }
        #assign parameters as required 
        #NB: these don't need declare statements in our query; so a query of 'select @demo myDemo' would be sufficient for us to pass in a parameter with name @demo and have it used
        #we can also pass in parameters that don't exist; they're simply ignored (sometimes useful if writing generic code that has optional params)
        $Params.Keys | %{$cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@$_", $Params[$_]) | out-null}

        $reader = $cmd.ExecuteReader()
        while (-not ($reader.IsClosed)) {
            $table = new-object 'System.Data.DataTable'
            $table.Load($reader)
            write-verbose "TableName: $($table.TableName)" #NB: table names aren't always available
            $table | Select-Object -ExcludeProperty RowError, RowState, Table, ItemArray, HasErrors
        }

    }
    end {
        $connection.Close()
    }
}
```

Comment: Code with syntax highlighting available here: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/JohnLBevan/4c791aa60e85a2e992eff4f415267d47/ (slightly tweaked from the above; but not significantly so).